# Performance implications of defining render props function within render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render

**Take the following example code:**

```js
class Something extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
      <SomeProvider
        render={providedProps => (
          <SomeChild {...providedProps}/>
        )}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

**Every React render props article uses this pattern as an example, but it's generally bad practice to define functions inline. Is this an exception to that rule?**

Is there any benefit to defining the function outside of render?

```js
class Something extends Component {
  renderSomeChild = providedProps => (
    <SomeChild {...providedProps}/>
  )

  render() {
   return (
      <SomeProvider
        render={this.renderSomeChild}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion was correct that the `renderProps` function should not be re-declared within the `render` function - or else it will force re-renders. I confirmed this [Why Did You Render?](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render)

Comment: correct, this is why render props is not the best pattern, but it has its use cases

Answer (score 0):

At this "function outside case" the const renderSomeChild (i suposed it is cause you did'nt mention) just make a reference to an allocated function in memory. So, if you aren't planning to reuse that function it make no sense to use it outside, i really think this make no significant  on performance...

A way to use the first example as the best practices is to write a code like this:

```
 class Something extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
      <SomeProvider>
        {providedProps => (
          <SomeChild {...providedProps}/>
        )}
      </SomeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope the above code will help you! :)

Comment: But, I believe that defining the render function inline guarantees that the `SomeProvider` component will re-render because the new `render` function prop isn't equal to the previous one, right?

Comment: Only when extends React.PureComponent.

Comment: That can't be correct. If something would trigger a re-render for a `extends PureComponent` then it would, of necessity, cause a re-render for `extends Component`

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I understood what you meant and yes! You're right! What I mean is that, even when you extend a React.PureComponent, it will create a new function in the render (). The way to avoid this is to use your instance method. :)